# Proof of an estimate in the PDE book by Gilbarg and Trudinger

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

[image]

> I have worked out the proof of (7.32), but I don't know how to use it to derive the inequality circled in red ink. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you write down what $V1$ and $\|h\|$ are?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the definition of $r$ is given by $r=(1-\delta)^{-1}$, so 
$h^r=|x-y|^{n\frac{\mu-1}{1-\delta}}=|x-y|^{n(\frac{\mu-\delta}{1-\delta}-1)}$. Now use (7.32) to conclude the result.